# Теряется значение при входе в функцию(любую, что addstud, что viewinfo)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct list
{
    char sur[128];
    int  ball;
    int  mark;
}list;
int addstud(char *std,list stud[100]);
int viewinfo(char *std, int n);

int main()
{
 list stud[100];
 int n=0,i=0,menu;
 char std[] = "stud.txt";

 while (1)
 {
    printf("1)Add new student\n2)Show list of students\n3)Change info about student\n4)Delete student\n5)Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&menu);
    switch (menu)
    {
 case 1:
        printf("Enter Surname student: ");
        scanf("%s",&(stud[i].sur));
        printf("Enter student scores: ");
        scanf("%d",&stud[i].ball);
        stud[i].mark = 0;
        printf("#1:%d)%-9s",i,stud[i].sur);   
        addstud(std,stud);
        i++;
        n=i;
        break;
 case 2:
        viewinfo(std,n);
        break;
 case 5:
        return 0;
 default:
        printf("Eror, please try again!");
        system("cls");
    }

 }
}

int addstud(char *std,list stud[100])
{
    FILE *fl;
    fl  = fopen(std, "a");
    int i = 0;
    if (fl == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    i++;
    printf("#2:%d)%-9s",i,stud[i].sur);   
    fprintf(fl,"%d)%-9s",i,stud[i].sur);
    fprintf(fl,"%-4d",stud[i].ball);
    fprintf(fl,"%-3d\n",stud[i].mark);
    fclose(fl);
    printf("The student's addition was successfully completed!\n Press Enter for continue...\n");
    getch();
    //system("cls");
}

int viewinfo(char *std, int n)
{
    FILE *fl;
    list stud[100];
    fl  = fopen(std, "r");
    int x;
    int i = 0;
    if (fl == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i; i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d)%-9s%-4d%-3d\n",i+1,stud[i].sur,stud[i].ball,stud[i].mark);
    }

    fclose(fl);
}
```

Comment: Небось передаёте что-нибудь по значению?

Comment: Читаю с клавиатуры, записываю в структуру(по задумке должен быть еще и индекс этой запис), но при в ходе в другую функцию значение теряется('printf("#1:%d)%-9s",i,stud[i].sur); ' 'printf("#2:%d)%-9s",i,stud[i].sur); ' - проверяю этими строчками)